# Combined Shapley Values for Probability Models

Tags: probability, python, conditional-probability, shapley-value

Using Python I have created two separate XGBoost probability models. From these two models, I compute a final value by multiplying the outputs (probabilities) together to give a probability of both events happening at the same time.

I would like to be able to explain the output of the final value using Shapley values computed using the shap library (https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Previously I have attempted to use shap.KernelExplainer to explain the output function. This works, but I have found this to be very slow when I use enough of my dataset to create an accurate background for the explainer.

I have the shap.Explainer for both of the individual models which work quickly. I am attempting to find a way to use the shap values of the individual models to create the final shap values, but am struggling to do so. For example:

```
Model_1 Probability = 0.5, Feature_1 Contribution = 0.3, Feature_2 Contribution = 0.2

Model_2 Probability = 0.2, Feature_1 Contribution = 0.05, Feature_2 Contribution = 0.15

Computed Probability = 0.1, Feature_1 Contribution = ?, Feature_2 Contribution = ?
```

Is there a formula to determine the contributions of the individual features to the computed probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additive nature of the Shapley values to the output of the individual models, in general it doesn't seem possible to factor their product in the third line below back into additive contributions of each input without also getting cross terms.

[image]